# Why does the C++ standard not mention __STDC_IEC_559__?

Tags: c++, c++11

According to C++11 standard [c.math], the `<cmath>` header is same as Standard C library header `<math.h>`.
(Of course, there are several differences, --- namespace, overloads etc. --- but these can be ignored here.)
And according to C99 standard annex F, "An implementation that defines `__STDC_IEC_559__` shall conform to the specifications in" the annex F.

Ex. The `atan2` may cause a domain error if both arguments are zero, but It must not if `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined.

In C99, many behavior is also dependent on whether `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined or not.

However, it seems that `__STDC_IEC_559__` is not mentioned anywhere in C++11 standard.
If so, shall a C++ implementation conform to the specifications in the annex F?

I think that `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559()` is a substitute, but it seems to mention about only type.

Comment: I think you'll find it's because the C++ standards don't completely redefine the C standards where it comes to the runtime library, but include them by reference, so they don't have to cite everything the C standards cite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard (n3797) includes the C standard library by reference, see s1.2/2.

> The library described in Clause 7 of ISO/IEC 9899:1999 and Clause 7 of ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.1:2001
>   and Clause 7 of ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.2:2003 is hereinafter called the C standard library.
>
> With the qualifications noted in Clauses 18 through 30 and in C.4, the C standard library is a subset of the C++ standard
>   library.

The standard contains no mention of that symbol, and I would not expect it be defined, since it appears to be specific to Standard C. By not defining that symbol, C++ is not bound by the contents of Annex F.

Instead the C++ standard contains multiple mentions of IEC 559 in a rather more C++-like form. For example,

> Shall be true for all specializations in which `is_iec559 != false`

There is a specific mention in 18.3.2.4/56.

> static constexpr bool is_iec559;
>
> True if and only if the type adheres to IEC 559 standard.218
>
> Meaningful for all floating point types.

I think it would be fair to say that C++ includes all the same capabilities (or lack of them), but adapted to the C++ world.

Comment: "a conforming implementation has is_iec559 != false": Where is this stated in the spec?

Comment: It says "The following referenced documents are indispensable for the application of this document." That is not inclusion by reference. Other C macros like `__STDC_MB_MIGHT_NEQ_WC__` are defined by C++.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: the extent to which the C++ standard includes the C standard library is spelled out in clauses 18 to 30 and Appendix C.4. It all seems clear enough to me.

Comment: @david.pfx Your first paragraph sounds like it implies that the macro is required by C++. Now I see that the second paragraph seems to go the other way. Either way, you don't mention whether or how C++ might reference Annex F. This answer seems confusing and incomplete.

Comment: See edit. C++ is not obliged to define the symbol, and it seems to me is free to substitute a more C++-like approach.