# should ldexp round correctly

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, floating-point

I'm a bit surprised with MSVC ldexp behavior (it happens in Visual Studio 2013, but also with all older versions at least down to 2003...).

For example:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double g=ldexp(2.75,-1074);
    double e=ldexp(3.0,-1074);

    printf("g=%g e=%g \n",g,e);
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
g=9.88131e-324 e=1.4822e-323
```

The first one g is strangely rounded...
It is 2.75 * fmin_denormalized, so i definitely expect the second result e.
If I evaluate `2.75*ldexp(1.0,-1074)` I correctly get same value as e.

Are my expectations too high, or does Microsoft fail to comply with some standard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the question does not explicitly state this, I assume that the output expected by the asker is:

```
g=1.4822e-323 e=1.4822e-323
```

This is what we would expect from a C/C++ compiler that promises strict adherence to IEEE-754. The question is tagged both `C` and `C++`, I will address `C99` here as that is the standard I have in hand.

In Annex F, which describes IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic (where IEC 60559 is basically another name for IEEE-754) the `C99` standard specifies:

> An implementation that defines `__STDC_IEC_559__` shall conform to the
>   specifications in this annex. [...] The `scalbn` and `scalbln`
>   functions in `<math.h>` provide the scalb function recommended in the
>   Appendix to IEC 60559.

Further down in that annex, section F.9.3.6 specifies:

> On a binary system, `ldexp(x, exp)` is equivalent to `scalbn(x, exp)`.

The appendix referenced by the `C99` standard is the appendix of the 1985 version of IEEE-754, where we find the scalb function defined as follows:

> Scalb(y, N) returns y × 2<sup>N</sup> for integral values N without computing 2<sup>N</sup>.

scalb is defined as a multiplication with a power of two, and multiplications must be rounded correctly based on the current rounding mode according to the standard. Therefore, with a conforming `C99` compiler `ldexp()` must return a correctly rounded result **if** the compiler defines `__STDC_IEC_559__`. In the absence of a library call setting the rounding mode, the default rounding mode "round to nearest or even" is in effect.

I do not have access to MSVC 2013, so I do not know whether it defines that symbol or not. This could even depend on a compiler flag setting, such as `/fp:strict`.

After tracking down my copy of the C++11 standard, I cannot find any reference to `__STDC_IEC_559__` or any language about IEEE-754 bindings. According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802294/why-does-the-c-standard-not-mention-stdc-iec-559) this is because that support is included by referring to the C99 standard.

Comment: This behavior happens with /fp:strict also. __STDC_IEC_559__ is not defined, so it at least is not promising to do it right... What standard MSVC 2013 complies to in C/C++ is another question...

Answer (score 2):

This happens because during the `ldexp` calculation the 2.75 gets truncated to 2, which happens because at that small of a denormalized number the bits that represent the '.75' part get shifted off the end of the representable number and disappear.  Whether this is a bug or designed behavior can be debated.

When calculating `2.75*ldexp(1.0,-1074)` normal rounding happens, and the 2.75 becomes 3.

EDIT: ldexp should round correctly, and this is a bug.

Comment: I think the OP is specifically asking for that debate.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I spent so much time in the debugger figuring out _why_ this happened I lost sight of what OP was asking.  I'd vote for **bug**.

Answer (score 0):

OP results do not fail to comply with the C spec as that spec does not define the preciseness of calculations.

OP result *may* have failed IEEE 754, but it depends on the rounding mode in use at the time, which is not posted.  Yet OP's reports `2.75*ldexp(1.0,-1074)` worked as expected implying at that time, the expected rounding mode was in effect.

Using `printf("%la",x)` aids in seeing clearly what is happening near the limits of `double`.

I would expect `g` to "round to nearest - ties to even" with the result of `0x1.8p-1073` - which did occur with gcc on windows.

Ideally `g` would have the value of `0x1.6p-1073`

```
0x0.0p-1073 Zero
0x0.8p-1073 next higher double DBL_TRUE_MIN
0x1.0p-1073 next higher double
0x1.6p-1073 ideal `g` answer, but not available as a double
0x1.8p-1073 next higher double
```

To be fair, it could be a processor bug - it has [happened before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug).

---

Ref

```
double g=ldexp(2.75,-1074);
printf("%la\n%la\n", 2.75,ldexp(2.75,-1074));
printf("%la\n%la\n", 3.0 ,ldexp(3.0 ,-1074));
double e=ldexp(3.0,-1074);
printf("%la\n%la\n", g,e);
printf("%la\n%la\n", 9.88131e-324, DBL_TRUE_MIN);
printf("g=%g e=%g \n",g,e);

0x1.6p+1
0x1.8p-1073
0x1.8p+1
0x1.8p-1073
0x1.8p-1073
0x1.8p-1073
0x1p-1073
0x1p-1074
g=1.4822e-323 e=1.4822e-323
```

Comment: Having stepped thru the code in the debugger, this is an algorithm bug, not a processor bug.